# Can we take python code as input in browser and return the output?

Tags: javascript, python, browser, interpreter, online-compilation

I tried some ways but I cannot figure out a way if we can take input (Python Code) in browser (JS) and run the code and return the output online without creating an online compiler?
I tried hitting some online interpreters urls with the code but it does not work.

I was wondering if I take input and can run it in my personal IDE/Editor and return the output online.

Is there any way or tool to make this possible?

Comment: sure just save it as a file and run it with `python input.py > output.txt` and then just read in output.txt ... of coarse a bad actor could do bad things to your computer

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: @CoderPerson I need to make an online time complexity calculator. I have made it in python using multiple inputs and making a graph and showing time complexity of the function but I need to do it in browser and host it on my website for my major project presentation.